# Insert but only if a condition on another table is met

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables for a messaging system

Conversations

```
| id |
```

Participants

```
| id | conversation | user |
```

Messages

```
| id | conversation | user | text |
```

I want to restrict messages being inserted into a conversation if the user is not part of through the participants table

I think I could structure it in a better way by having participant in the messages table. But then id have to do an extra query by seeing what a users participant id is before inserting a message.

Id rather do it with a constraint or foreign key. What would the best way to do this be?

Comment: This may or may not be programmable in a stored procedure. Otherwise would need code in whatever you are using to design GUI with. Code opens recordset of Participants table filtered for the participant of interest. If recordset is empty, don't create the other record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `EXISTS` in the `INSERT` statement:

```
INSERT INTO Messages(id, conversation, user, text)
SELECT :id, :conversation, :user, :text
FROM dual
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 
  FROM Participants 
  WHERE conversation = :conversation AND user = :user
)
```

If your version of MySql is 8.0+ you can omit `FROM DUAL`.

Replace `:id`, `:conversation`, `:user` and `:text` with the column values that you want to insert.

If `ID` is an autoincremented integer change to:

```
INSERT INTO Messages(conversation, user, text)
SELECT :conversation, :user, :text
................................
```

Or, first create a `UNIQUE` constraint for the combination of columns `conversation` and `user` in `Participants`:

```
ALTER TABLE Participants ADD CONSTRAINT unique_conv_user UNIQUE (conversation, user)
```

and then add a foreign key constraint for the combination of columns `conversation` and `user` in `Messages`:

```
ALTER TABLE Messages 
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_conv_user 
FOREIGN KEY (conversation, user) REFERENCES Participants(conversation, user);
```

This way you can only insert new rows in `Messages` if the combination of `conversation` and `user` already exists in `Participants`.

Comment: How would this effect the performance vs inserting without checking?

Comment: @WilliamDaniels any type of checking affects the performance of a query. Checking is your requirement, isn't it?

Comment: in the most efficiant way yes,  im thinking if its inserting 10k messages in a day, adding an extra check like this might cost more than its worth. Would this way be better than having it done through a constraint? if thats even possible

Comment: @WilliamDaniels of course a constraint is better, but I read in your comment in the other answer that you don't want a constraint.

Comment: No I would prefer a constraint if thats possible to link like that. Unless it would require a participant Id to be on the messages table. Then id have to do another query anyway so no point

Answer (score 0):

Is this a trick question?  You just described the main use case of referential integrity in a data base.  Make Messages.(ID, User) a foreign key of the Participants table.

Comment: No im not experienced in data integrity at all so the question might seem easy. But would this work since participants can send many messages

Comment: Yes, foreign key as I described says the combination of conversation id and user must exist within the Participants table.  The Primary Key of Messages is Conversation ID + User + Text sequence number, which leaves you one more degree of freedom to add multiple messages.